# Pass data between parent view controller and a second navigation controller using button

Tags: ios

I have created a signup form in the parent controller and integrated a navigation view controller. Then I connected both the controllers through push segue.

I am stuck with how to transfer data from `UITextField` in the parent view controller to the navigation controller using the click event of the button placed on the signup form.

Anybody please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When a segue is triggered, before the visual transition occurs, the storyboard runtime invokes **`prepareForSegue:sender:`** method of the current view controller.

By implementing this method, you can pass any needed data to the view controller that is about to be displayed.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"StoryboardIDOfViewControllerThatWillBeShown"]) 
{
        YourViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationViewController.dataToPass = _yourTextField.text;
    }
}
```

The best practice is to give each segue in your storyboard an unique identifier. This identifier is a string that your application uses to distinguish one segue from another.

Comment: you need to set the property in SecondViewController before you push it onto the navigation stack. Note that this happens in FirstViewController.m file. Can you please explain that, what I have to set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full description of [Passing Data Between View Controllers](http://prateekvjoshi.com/2014/02/16/ios-app-passing-data-between-view-controllers/).

Comment: It could be better, if you explain briefly about it.

Comment: Just read this doc it explained good enough to understand about data passing.